# map integers after SNMP "cbQosPoliceExceededPkt" object to interface

Tags: snmp

If I execute the `snmpwalk -v 2c -On -c public IOS-XR-router .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9` command I receive the list of `cbQosPoliceExceededPkt`(32 bits count of packets treated as non-conforming by the policing feature) objects for all the interfaces:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -On -c public IOS-XR-router .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9        
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.33939721.372808280 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.102008393.975936877 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.202106522.1856909852 = Counter32: 5003
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.240900878.497875428 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.260148678.721345944 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.482088944.1031735842 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.683352142.2105749243 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.710279877.1618983151 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.720156245.1259602979 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.722287380.1469694376 = Counter32: 3613
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.808980780.1628785777 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.969060048.1892486036 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1256901827.699601203 = Counter32: 50868
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1265105847.595091350 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1369606127.7660493 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1391464972.909798245 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1408499934.2009269877 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1754292523.1069220732 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1835241439.1897653915 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.1846028775.1163943827 = Counter32: 26472
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.2030356433.1030288340 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.2038932423.882247250 = Counter32: 0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.17.1.1.9.2041219745.566624230 = Counter32: 0
$
```

How can I map integers(for example `33939721.372808280` or `102008393.975936877`) to interfaces or `ifIndex`? For example `ifIndex` of interface which dropped 26472 packets is `508`, but I can not see a correlation between `1846028775.1163943827` and `508`.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> This table contains statistical information only, no configuration information associated with it. Therefore, it is indexed by the instance specific IDs,  such as **cbQosPolicyIndex** and **cbQosObjectsIndex**.

`cbQosServicePolicyTable` is indexed by `cbQosPolicyIndex` (i.e. the "meaningless" numbers you quoted) `CbQosServicePolicyEntry` contains `cbQosIfIndex` which is the ifIndex.

You may need to look through `ciscoCBQosMIB` to find the full picture. Honestly, it'd be faster and make more sense to telnet in and run CLI commands to get data. :-)

Comment: Thanks! How did you knew or find out that `cbQosServicePolicyEntry` contains the `cbQosIfIndex`(ifIndex for the interface to which the service is attached to)? And am I correct that ideally if I install the CISCO-CLASS-BASED-QOS-MIB and all its dependencies the `snmpget` or `snmpwalk` utility should be able to make sense of those `cbQosPolicyIndex` numbers, e.g. translate the `33939721.372808280` into something meaningful?

Comment: Martin, read the [description from Cisco's Object Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166). It even gives some examples of how to navigate the different policies that could be applied to an interface and how to match them to objects in these tables.

Comment: No. The index numbers have no meaning on their own. They have to be cross referenced to other tables to get back to the interface to which they are applied. (because a policy can be used on multiple interfaces, or multiple maps.)